# JQuery Variable Gets Object ID With Equals Value Set in Another Variable Which is not Evaluating

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(".RecentFeedToogle .Tab").click(function(e){

                width = $(this).attr('id');
                RecentBananzaNews = '164px';
                RecentRaffles = '112px';
                RecentArticles = '114px';
                RecentForumDiscussions = '109px';
                RecentCharitableNews = '182px';
                if ($(this).width() === 44) {

                    $(".RecentFeedToogle .Tab.Active").animate({width:'44px'},500);
                    $(".RecentFeedToogle .Tab").removeClass('Active');
                    $(this).animate({width: width },500);
                    $(this).addClass('Active');
                };
            });
</script>
```

`$(this).animate({width: width },500);` in my script, the `width : width`, the ' width'variable is returning the ID of the clicked object and not the additional variable value.

HTML goes like this:

```
<!-- Recent Feed Starts -->
            <div class="RecentFeed">

                <!-- Switch Feed Starts -->
                <div class="RecentFeedToogle">
                    <div class="Tab Active" id="RecentBananzaNews">
                        <div class="Icon"></div>
                        <div class="Title">Bananza News</div>
                        <div class="Arrow"></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: can you post the HTML section where you set the id value

Comment: You have "width = $(this).attr('id)" so yes: your witdh variable has the ID of the object!

Comment: Yes sure, just updated @Lepanto if you want to see the live version check [here](http://rafflebananza.com/Desktop/index.html) too. Thanks!

Comment: Yes @Matthijs however underneath that ID variable is a variable. Basically check the ID, then the Var of that ID for the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".RecentFeedToogle .Tab").click(function(e){
    var divwidth = '';
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'RecentBananzaNews'){
        divwidth = '164px';
    }
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'RecentRaffles'){
        divwidth = '112px';
    }
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'RecentArticles'){
        divwidth = '114px';
    }
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'RecentForumDiscussions'){
        divwidth = '109px';
    }
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'RecentCharitableNews'){
        divwidth = '182px';
    }
    if ($(this).width() === 44) {
        $(".RecentFeedToogle .Tab.Active").animate({width:'44px'},500);
        $(".RecentFeedToogle .Tab").removeClass('Active');
        $(this).animate({width: divwidth },500);
        $(this).addClass('Active');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Lepanto, this works perfectly! Will +1 once I've got some extra rep :)